# Custom RichTextBlock raise exception "Element is already the child of another element"

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I use `FlipView` control and inside `ItemTemplate` I have custom RichTextBlock with `Elements` property created like collection of `Run` elements. It works, however, sometimes I am receiving exception *"WinRT information: Element is already the child of another element."* And I really don't understand why.

Could somebody please explain me why it is happening?

Sample - http://1drv.ms/1yZM8a5

**Model** (contains test data)

```
public class Page
{
    public Page()
    {
        Data = new List<Run>();
        Data.Add(new Run { Text = "1" });
        Data.Add(new Run { Text = "2" });
        Data.Add(new Run { Text = "3" });
        Data.Add(new Run { Text = "4" });
        Data.Add(new Run { Text = "5" });
    }
    public IList<Run> Data { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel** (collection of pages for FlipView)

```
public ObservableCollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }

// test data
Pages = new ObservableCollection<Page>();
Pages.Add(new Page()); // etc
```

**XAML**

```
<FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ExtendedRichTextBlock Elements="{Binding Data}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

**ExtendedRichTextBlock**

`Elements` is dependency property and changes are caught here:

```
private static void OnElementsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ExtendedRichTextBlock sender = d as ExtendedRichTextBlock;

    if (sender != null)
    {
        sender.Content.Blocks.Clear();

        var x = e.NewValue as IList<Run>;
                
        if (x != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in x)
            {
                var p = new Paragraph();
                p.Inlines.Add(item);    // WinRT information: Element is already the child of another element.

                sender.Content.Blocks.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Conclusion**

Just short conclusion from my discussion with Romasz in this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69598/discussion-between-romasz-and-kubakista).

> Every time the event is fired you are clearing content and then populating it reusing Run elements. In the behind it may be quite complex - maybe some animations, transitions and so on, I'm also not sure if this is not made asynchronously - if so there may be situation when elements still have a parent and you try to reuse it. Consider better thing, populating every time with UI elements it's not a good idea - make your datatemlate with those UI elements and bind their content to some kind of collection.

So all elements must be created on the fly in OnElementsChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your program sometimes tries to make *Run* element a child of another control, while it already has a parent and UI elemnts can have only one parent.

In this case consider little change in your app:

```cs
private static void OnElementsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ExtendedRichTextBlock sender = d as ExtendedRichTextBlock;

    if (sender != null)
    {
        sender.Content.Blocks.Clear();

        var x = e.NewValue as IList<string>;

        if (x != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in x)
            {
                var p = new Paragraph();
                p.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = item });    // WinRT information: Element is already the child of another element.
                sender.Content.Blocks.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course to make this work you need to change all `IList<Run>` to `IList<string>`.

This would ensure that every *Run* element is a new one without parent.

Comment: I guess it won't compile. `e.NewValue (IList<Run>)` can't be cast to `IList<String>`

Comment: @kennyzx You are right. I treat it as quite obvious and the OP will have to change the whole implementation - I just marked the problematic code.

Comment: _"your program sometimes tries to make Run element a child of another control"_ Ok, I understand, but any idea why is it happening?

Comment: @kubakista Every time the event is fired you are clearing content and then populating it reusing *Run* elements. In the behind it may be quite complex - maybe some animations, transitions and so on, I'm also not sure if this is not made asynchronously - if so there may be situation when elements still have a parent and you try to reuse it. Consider better thing, populating every time with UI elements it's not a good idea - make your datatemlate with those UI elements and bind their content to some kind of collection.

Comment: _"make your datatemlate with those UI elements and bind their content to some kind of collection."_ I am not sure if I understand and also I cannot bind to `RichTextBlock.Blocks`.

Comment: @kubakista It depends on what you want to put in your view. If you know the number of *Run* then put them once and bind their *Text* property to collection of strings. You may also think of using LIstView or other control. The main idea is not to make controls on the fly.

Comment: I will explain whole my idea. Every item inside `FlipView` represents article and each article is created from complex structure of `Paragraph(s)` with `Run` elements due to text formatting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69598/discussion-between-romasz-and-kubakista).